# Disable inline editing of rich text fields in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, richtext-editor

How can I disable inline editing of rich text fields in Experience Editor?
I still want the users to be able to click the edit icon in the toolbar popup (leftmost icon in the attached screenshot) so that they can go to the full editor, but I don't want them to be able to insert text directly onto the page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute JavaScript on page load that will set *contenteditable* attribute to false for all text boxes.

```
$(".scWebEditInput").attr("contenteditable", false)
```

Comment: Probably want to target `$("[scfieldtype='rich text']")` rather than *all* editable fields.

Comment: I put this in document.ready but it didn't change the `contenteditable` attribute. This is probably because Experience Editor adds the content and functionality after the document is ready, so that when I add my modification, it is overwritten by Experience Editor later. Do you have any tips on which other events I can do this on to not have it overwritten by Experience Editor later?

Comment: I ended up using a MutationObserver in my JS to listen for changes to the `contenteditable` attribute on the `$("[scfieldtype='rich text']")` elements. Whenever it is changed to something other than `false`, I forcibly set it back to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `bool` value you want to use to toggle editability during rendering time, you can also do it by passing in the `DisableEditable` parameter to the `Editable()` method like so:

```
// Set this variable to false to disable the editability in Experience Editor
bool shouldBeEditable = false;
@Html.Glass().Editable(Model, x => x.Title, shouldBeEditable ? "DisableEditable=true" : null)
```